# How to pass parameters in searchconsole('v1')

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

I am trying to use search console API using nodejs. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/44.0.0/searchconsole/classes/Searchconsole.html#info

I am trying to add the params like view id and date but it's not working.

```
google.searchconsole('v1').data({
        'auth': jwtClient,
        'ids':  view_id,
        'start-date': '8daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday',
        'dimensions': 'date',
       
        'max-results': 1000,
    }
```

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: It has only function for mobile friendly test. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/searchconsole/classes/Resource$Urltestingtools$Mobilefriendlytest.html
I think you should use webmaster API (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/webmasters/query.js)

Comment: @YonghoonLee i am not sure. i am trying to fetch  Landing page report under search console. Can you please suggest if i need to use webmaster API. 


i need to pull impressions, clicks, ctr etc metrics which show under landing pages

Comment: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3
I think this is the API what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot  and sorry for late response. I tried this one 


 google.webmasters('v3').searchAnalytics.query({
                'auth': jwtClient,
                'start-date': '8daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday',
                'dimensions': 'ga:date',
                'siteUrl': myURL,
                'max-results': 1000,
            }).then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);

            });
but getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Comment: Never mind. i am able to mange it